# Listbox doesn't add sentence

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void btVer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbConteudo.Items.Clear(); // limpar listbox

    string caminho = tbCaminho.Text; //criação da string com o caminho da pasta
    string letra = tbLetra.Text; //criação da string com a primeira letra da pasta

    string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(caminho, letra + "*"); //criação da string com o diretório da pasta

    if (letra != null)
    {
        lbConteudo.Items.Add("Número de pastas começadas com a letra " + letra + ": " + dir.Length); //adição de um item com o título da pesquisa

        foreach (string a in dir)
            lbConteudo.Items.Add(a); //procurar e adicionar as pastas começadas pela letra indicada pelo utilizador
    } //se o utilizador colocar uma letra 
    else
    {
        lbConteudo.Items.Add("Número de pastas: " + System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(caminho).Length); // adição das pastas
    } // se não colocar letra
}
```

[image: try with letter]

[image: try with no letter]

It says the same sentence in the "else version" while it should say it only if I put a letter in, not if its null...

Comment: It's really hard to read your code, since variables and comments aren't written in English.

Comment: `if (letra != null)` This will always be `true` (so you will never enter the `else`). Textboxes don't return `null`. Did you mean `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(letra))`?

Comment: You should easily be able to debug this yourself. Just put a breakpijt and see what `letra` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Text` property will not be `null` if it is empty. It can be a `string.Empty` / `""` or simply some spaces or tabs, which probably will also not satisfy your prerequisites.  You need to use [string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_IsNullOrWhiteSpace_System_String_) to check for the lack of a usefull string value:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(letra))
```